# How to get data from a named json with golang+jason?

Tags: json, go

I've this json:

```
info = {"key1": 1 , "key2": 1 , "key3": 3}
```

I would like to get the value from `key1` with [jason](https://github.com/antonholmquist/jason) and `NewObjectFromReader`.

I'm using this code:

```
statusBody, err := jason.NewObjectFromReader(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

`res.Body` is a `io.Reader`, so that part is fine (I guess). `go run` shows this problem:

```
2018/12/19 18:02:40 invalid character 'i' looking for beginning of value
```

I think the problem is that the json starts with `info=` instead of `{`. Any idea how to parse this json?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info =` is not valid JSON. Therefore, you have to start reading where the `{` begins and stop reading with the final closing `}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.